# Ejecutar .exe desde Servicio de Windows

Tags: c#

Estoy intentanto abrir una aplicacion desde un servicio de Windows pero no se ejecuta. Estoy utilizando `Process.Start(Path);` pero no me funciona.

Utilizo Visual Studio 2015 - C#

Comment: el log de eventos dice por qué no arranca?

Comment: no muestra ningun error en el Log de eventos

Comment: si la aplicación genera los csv y el envío pero no el webservice no sera problema de firewall?

Answer (score 0):

En principio no es posible arrancar una aplicación desde un servicio de Windows.

Los servicios de Windows no corren en el contexto de ningún usuario en concreto, y no permiten ningún tipo de interacción con el usuario (no pueden mostrar un formulario por ejemplo).

Dependiendo de por qué y de qué tipo de aplicación quieres lanzar, tal vez se pueda buscar alguna solución alternativa. Pero en ningun caso va ser tan sencillo como un `Process.Start`.

P.D. esto es así si no me equivoco empezando en Windows Vista. En anteriores versiones si era posible.

Comment: Mi aplicacion lo que hace generar unos archivos .csv, enviarlas a un correo y luego a una WebService. La creacion de archivos y el envio de correo si lo hace pero no envia los archivos a la WebService. Mi duda ahora es si esto pueda deberse a la forma de inicio de la Applicacion desde el Servicio.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente la tarea esté en marcha, pero tú no la verás porque por defecto los servicios se ejecutan bajo la cuenta SYSTEM.

Prueba lo siguiente:

1. Edita el servicio que invoca la app. Ves a pestaña "log on" y selecciona "This account". Escribe tu usuario y password.

   [image: servicio-cambio-usuario]
2. Para y vuelve a arrancar el servicio.

Obviamente esto tiene la limitación de que tienes que conocer un usuario y password del usuario que va a necesitar el servicio.

Además, no "funcionará" para varios usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

En el mejor de los casos, en batch "CMD"

```
start "ruta del programa".exe
```

. lo que tendrías que hacer es lo mismo pero ya no abririas el *.exe si no el .*cmd o *.bat